# How to configure S3 event on a bucket to trigger lambda with ansible

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, ansible

I am trying to configure s3 bucket event notification to trigger a lambda function through ansible.

ansible modules aws_s3 or s3_bucket does not seem to support this. Please let me know if there is any way we can configure this with ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mention of "notifications" in [`devel/.../s3_bucket.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/s3_bucket.py), although [boto3.s3 supports it](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.10/reference/services/s3.html#bucketnotification)

So, the answer to your question is to copy the `s3_bucket.py` into the [`library/` folder of your playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally), add the desired call, and then if you're feeling generous submit a PR to the ansible project to allow others to benefit from that improvement.

Or, as [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally) says, you can also put it in any of the `$ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` paths (such as `~/.ansible/plugins/modules` or, [with the correct `ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/reference_appendices/config.html#default-module-path), a top-level `.ansible/plugins/modules`) to make it visible to every playbook, but that can be a lot more work to distribute if no other playbook needs access to that bleeding edge feature.